# Operational Transfomation: transformation function

Tags: typescript, operational-transform, collaborative-editing

I'm implementing a TypeScript library to handle concurrent editing of documents represented by strings, using [Operational Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation). In the beginning the documents where one line strings (without '\n') and my transformation function worked, now I want to consider the document as a char matrix and change the function to fit the new case.

In the beginning the operations were objects of type:

```
interface Operation {
    type: 'ins' | 'del';
    id: string;
    char: string;
    pos: number;
}
```

Where **type** specifies if the operation inserts or deletes characters, **id** is the user id, **char** is the inserted or deleted character, and **pos** is the position (starting by 0) at which the operation should be applied. The transformation function that I used was the following:

- inserting a char in a position *x* that follows the position *y* of a previous insert operation leads to a change of the parameter *x* to *x+1*
- inserting a char in a position *x* that follows the position *y* of a previous delete operation leads to a change of the parameter *x* to *x-1*
- deleting a char in a position *x* that follows the position *y* of a previous insert operation leads to a change of the parameter *x* to *x+1*
- deleting a char in a position *x* that follows the position *y* of a previous delete operation leads to a change of the parameter *x* to *x-1*

```
function transformOperation(op1: Operation, op2: Operation) {
    switch ([op1.type, op2.type].join(' ')) {
      case 'ins ins':
        if ((Number(op1.pos) < Number(op2.pos)) ||
            (Number(op1.pos) == Number(op2.pos) &&
            (op1.id > op2.id))) {
          return op1;
        }
        return { ...op1, pos: op1.pos + 1 };

      case 'ins del':
        if (Number(op1.pos) <= Number(op2.pos)) {
          return op1;
        }
        return { ...op1, pos: op1.pos - 1 };

      case 'del ins':
        if (Number(op1.pos) < Number(op2.pos)) {
          return op1;
        }
        return { ...op1, pos: op1.pos + 1 };

      case 'del del':
        if (Number(op1.pos) <= Number(op2.pos)) {
          return op1;
        }
        return { ...op1, pos: op1.pos - 1 }

      default:
        return op1;
    }
}
```

Then I started considering the documents as characters matrices, the operations became:

```
interface Operation {
    type: 'ins' | 'del';
    id: string;
    text: string;
    startRow: number;
    startCol: number;
    endRow: number;
    endCol: number;
    range: number;
}
```

Where **text** replaces **char** given that more than one char could be inserted or deleted; the position in the doc is given by the four properties **startRow**, **startCol**, **endRow**, **endCol** and the **range** is the number of characters inserted or deleted.

The new transformation function is:

```
function samePosition(op1: Operation, op2: Operation) {
    return (op1.startRow == op2.startRow) && (op1.startCol == op2.startCol)
}

function preceeding(op1: Operation, op2: Operation) {
    return [op1.startRow, op1.startCol] < [op2.startRow, op2.startCol]
}

function modifiedCol(op: Operation, delta: number): Operation {
    return {
        ...op,
        startCol: op.startCol + delta,
        endCol: op.endCol + delta,
    };
}

function transformOperation(op1: Operation, op2: Operation): Operation {
    switch (`${op1.type} ${op2.type}`) {
        case 'ins ins':
            if (preceeding(op1, op2) || samePosition(op1, op2) && (op1.clientId > op2.clientId)) {
                return op1;
            }
            return modifiedCol(op1, op2.text.length);

        case 'ins del':
            if (preceeding(op1, op2) || samePosition(op1, op2)) {
                return op1;
            }
            return modifiedCol(op1, -op2.range);

        case 'del ins':
            if (preceeding(op1, op2)) {
                return op1;
            }
            return modifiedCol(op1, op2.text.length);

        case 'del del':
            if (preceeding(op1, op2) || samePosition(op1, op2)) {
                return op1;
            }
            return modifiedCol(op1, -op2.range);

        default: return op1;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work in certain cases, I'll describe one.

Imagine two users *u1* and *u2* with the document 'ciao**\n**mondo', when they have this copy of the document they apply respectively:

```
op1 = { type: 'ins', range:7, id: '2', text: 'p', startCol: 3, endCol: 5, startRow: 0, endRow: 1 }

//and

op2 = { type: 'ins', range:6, id: '1', text: 'n', startCol: 3, endCol: 4, startRow: 0, endRow: 1 }
```

If *u1* applies

```
op1 = { type: 'ins', range:7, id: '1', text: 'p', startCol: 3, endCol: 5, startRow: 0, endRow: 1 }
```

it obtains **ciap**, and then if it receives

```
op2 = { type: 'ins', range:6, id: '2', text: 'n', startCol: 3, endCol: 4, startRow: 0, endRow: 1 }
```

then trying to transform op2 against op1 with the previous function it obtains

```
op2' = { type: 'ins', range:6, id: '1', text: 'n', startCol: 4, endCol: 5, startRow: 0, endRow: 1 }
```

but it is not correct since the end row remained the same even the new text doesn't have a second line; this implies that the new operation cannot be applied to the document.

I think it is not the only case and I suppose I should consider also the change of row values in the function, any idea of what should be the new function?